# phpMyAdmin unable to connect with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I had installed MAMP on my windows 10 machine. I had then configured the MySQL thru the phpMyAdmin and had installed the WordPress. Later due to certain issues, I had to un-install and re-install the MAMP again. This time Apache started running and I could reach localhost/MAMP/, but when I click on phpMyAdmin, I get the message:

> "mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002) No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it

.....You should check the host, user name and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server". I ran the command> `MySQL -u root -p status`. It asked for a password. On giving the password, I got the following: `Error 2003 (HY000) Can't connect to MySQL server on localhost (10061)`.

Please help with a workaround.

Comment: When I type http://localhost/phpmyadmin, I get message: "The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server."

Comment: the mysql service is running?

Comment: write sudo before MySQL -u root -p status

Comment: mysql should be running because it did ask for the password. Kindly let me know what does 'sudo' indicate and if it should be used for windows m/c? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was resolved thru re-installation and taking care to disable the installation of MAMP Pro which happens by default.

Answer (score 0):

I usually see the "actively refused" error when I try to connect to a port that the MySQL server is not actually running on. That said, I don't know why this would happen out of the blue. Maybe you should be using [WAMP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/) instead of MAMP?

You could probably troubleshoot this issue remotely with third party tools that have debug logging ([MySQLShell](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/shell/) through its [Application Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-application-log.html))

Comment: In what way is WAMP different from MAMP? Instead should I uninstall mysql specifically before re-installing MAMP?

Answer (score 0):

Check all your Microsoft Redistribute Packages are installed correctly. If the problem exist then use the XAMPP or WAMP for the Windows because MAMP is generally used for the MAC OS.

Comment: How can I be sure, the situation won't repeat for XAMPP or WAMP. In what way they are different from MAMP? I had installed the windows version of MAMP. It was working fine till the complete installation of wordpress. Started giving trouble only when I decided to uninstall and re-install the MAMP. Thanks for your help.